# angularjs: $resolve block is executing before controller

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying to make an `$http api` call inside `app config` of angularjs .Below is the code for $http api call.

```
         .when('/programme/:programmename', {                          
          templateUrl:"programme/info.html" ,

          resolve: {
            execute: function(userAPI,$rootScope,$route){
                var url = $route.current.params.programmename;
                url = url.replace(/-/g, ' ') ;
                userAPI.getProgrammeid({programmename: url } , function(r){
                $rootScope.Programmeid= r.getprogrammeidbyname.programmeidbyname.programmeid }

                )}
                }

  })
```

As per Angularjs documentation resolve block executes before controller and template, however in my case controller is executing before resolve block
I tried out promises but I am getting stuck in it.
Is this because of `$http api call which is (userAPI.getProgrammeid({programmename: url }.....)` inside `resolve block`?.
I am a bit confused

please help me out this.

Comment: Why did you put Ruby tags on this question?

Comment: @CWSpear I am using Ruby on Rails as back end and AngularJs as front end.Sorry for the misunderstanding if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `execute` actually return anything? It needs to return a promise that is resolved when the your function is done doing it's thing.

I think you are misunderstanding how to use resolve. It's to fetch something to inject into your controller. If the goal is to get the `programmeid`, then the resolve would look something like this:

```
resolve: {
    programmeid: function (userAPI, $q, $route) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var url = $route.current.params.programmename;
        url = url.replace(/-/g, ' ') ;
        userAPI.getProgrammeid({ programmename: url }, function (r) {
            deferred.resolve(r.getprogrammeidbyname.programmeidbyname.programmeid);
            // now that our promise is resolved, our controller should execute
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

and then you can get access to it in your controller like so:

```
app.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, programmeid) {
    $scope.programmeid = programmeid;
});
```

Comment: @CWSpear.Thanks
The code helped me and it is working perfectly.Thanks a lot.
The angularjs documentation is not helping and takes time to understand.Can u recommend any other sites which i can visit to sharpen my skills.Am looking at egghead.io

Comment: @PeeVee Unfortunately, I don't have any other solid, reliable sources that I use. Just lots of Googling, and the docs *are* getting better. There was like 1 line of docs for resolve when I first tried figuring this out. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the help...But the docs are not very good for beginners like myself but looking at various sources to get experience at angularjs.